# Match the columns of a table from another table to get the desired column in the main table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have this data.table.

```
library(data.table)
class<- c("a","c","v","f","r","b","t","o");
value<-c(0.76,  0.91,   1.94,   0.37,   1.35,   0.75,   1.95,   1.69);
vehicle<-c("we",    "df",   "rt",   "yh",   "uj",   "er",   "ed","we")
carbon<-c(0.984,    0.27,   0.419,  0.469,  0.132,  0.865,  0.562,  0.133)
cap<-c(3,   2,  1,  6,  "y",    "t",    4,  6)
up<-c(4,    2,  3,  "d",    "t",    "y",    "u",    "i")
down<-c("t",    "e",    "r",    3,  4,  5,  2,  1)
amt<-c( 34, 23, 12, 67, 87, 43, 23, 12)
df<-data.table(class,value,vehicle,carbon,cap,up,down,amt)
```

and this another mapping table

```
up<-c("d","i",4)
vehicle<-c("yh",    "we",   "we")
exercise<-c("ty",45,    "k")
map<-data.table(cbind(vehicle,up,exercise))
```

i need the column `exercise` in the table `df`

I am currently using this code, which produces the desired results. and I am happy with it.

```
df[,names(map)[length(names(map))]:= 
                map$exercise[match(do.call(paste0,df[, which(names(df) %in% names(map)[1:(ncol(map)-1)]),with = FALSE]),
                                                   do.call(paste0,map[,1:(ncol(map)-1)]))] ]
```

So basically what this code does is.

1. identify the columns from mapping table in the main table.
2. concatenate those columns.
3. do a match of these concatenated columns with the concatenated columns of mapping table.
4. index the desired column from mapping table and fix it to the main table.

So the desired result is

```
> df$exercise
[1] "k"  NA   NA   "ty" NA   NA   NA   "45"
```

But sometimes columns of the mapping table order is changed.

for e.g. changed mapping table is
Notice that now the order is up and then vehicle. and in this case the above code will not produce the desired result, infact it would be all NA.

```
up<-c("d","i",4)
vehicle<-c("yh",    "we",   "we")
exercise<-c("ty",45,    "k")
map<-as.data.frame(cbind(up,vehicle,exercise))
setDT(map)
```

So my code only works if the order of the columns in mapping table is same as in the main table.
If my code can be changed to perform the same results but considering the order of the columns.
ideally  would want this as dynamic as possible.

mapping table can have as many columns as in the main table and an additional column which needs to be inserted in the main table.

Please comment if you need any further clarification.
I would appreciate if my given code can be edited and provided.
any other code is also welcome.
I prefer data.table package use.

Comment: The simple `dplyr` command `left_join(df, map)` produces the exact output of your code and may be more flexible.

Comment: Or, if you want to keep it in `data.table` you can use `merge(df, map, all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: If a join is **not** what you want, then please describe the operation you are doing in words, not just in code. Otherwise I suggest closing as a duplicate of the [How to merge/join R-FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right), which includes a nice answer specific to `data.table`.

Comment: basically i am concatenating the columns in the main table and then matching them in the concatenated columns of mapping table. but since order is not the same, match doesnt work.

Comment: ```merge(df, map, all.x = TRUE)``` this doesnt work.

Comment: @Mohit `merge(df, map, all.x = TRUE)` does work on your sample data, it just reorders the columns and rows. Does it not work in your real data? You may need to update your sample data to better select your real data. Does the `dplyr` solution work?  If you could be more explicit about why this (or the `dplyr` solution) doesn't suffice we could help you more, but "doesn't work" doesnt provide much for us to go on (an error? unanticipated result?)

Comment: @jpsmith, ```merge(df, map, all.x = TRUE)```  this works only when order of columns of main and mapping table are same. but wont work if any of the column in mapping table are before. in the above e.g. you can see that the mapping table is ```cbind(up,vehicle,exercise)```.

Comment: I think the discussion is going in circles, Mohit. Using `out <- df[,names(map)[length...` (from your code block that you said words), then `out <- out[order(class,value,vehicle),]` (just to ensure comparison later), I can do both `left_join(df, map)[order(class,value,vehicle),][,.SD,.SDcols=names(out)] |> all.equal(out)` and `merge(df, map, all.x = TRUE)[order(class,value,vehicle),][,.SD,.SDcols=names(out)] |> all.equal(out)` and the are both `TRUE`. If it doesn't work for you, then it is because of some difference between the sample data above and your real data.

Comment: That difference is not something we can know or infer, unfortunately. If the difference is only in column order or row order, then ... that problem is mostly aesthetic unless you can show substantive problems with it ... and if so, it is easily remedied. If the difference is more, then the impetus is on you to clearly demonstrate what is not working about this. The question reads very much with "merge/join" as the solution, please help us to understand what breaks. *"this also doesn't work"* does not.

Comment: Side note: never do `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`, you corrupt (cast into strings) your numeric data. Just use `data.frame(...)`. Or better yet, `data.table(...)` directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255477/discussion-between-mohit-and-r2evans).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works perfectly and should always be preferred.

```
setcolorder(map[df, on = .NATURAL], union(names(df), names(map)))[]
```

The other code in the answers to this question doesn't considers any irregularities in the mapping.

Thank you [Merijn-van-tilborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10415749/merijn-van-tilborg) for your valuable contribution.

Comment: There is nothing here that is not in my answer, other than column-order which you never identified as a requirement. Downvoting as it adds very little to the existing discussions.

Comment: I have no objections. That is something derived from your research.

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest issue here is not the basic mechanism of a merge/join, it's doing so when the columns to join on are not known, and the columns to join into `df` are also not known.

I suggest this is a reasonable approach:

```r
df <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(class = c("a", "c", "v", "f", "r", "b", "t", "o"), value = c(0.76, 0.91, 1.94, 0.37, 1.35, 0.75, 1.95, 1.69), vehicle = c("we", "df", "rt", "yh", "uj", "er", "ed", "we"), carbon = c(0.984, 0.27, 0.419, 0.469, 0.132, 0.865, 0.562, 0.133), cap = c("3", "2", "1", "6", "y", "t", "4", "6"), up = c("4", "2", "3", "d", "t", "y", "u", "i"), down = c("t", "e", "r", "3", "4", "5", "2", "1"), amt = c(34, 23, 12, 67, 87, 43, 23, 12)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" )))
map <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(up = c("d", "i", "4"), vehicle = c("yh", "we", "we"), exercise = c("ty", "45", "k")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L)))

(same <- intersect(names(map), names(df)))
# [1] "up"      "vehicle"
(diff <- setdiff(names(map), names(df)))
# [1] "exercise"
if (length(same) && length(diff)) 
  df[map, c(diff) := mget(diff), on = same]
#     class value vehicle carbon    cap     up   down   amt exercise
#    <char> <num>  <char>  <num> <char> <char> <char> <num>   <char>
# 1:      a  0.76      we  0.984      3      4      t    34        k
# 2:      c  0.91      df  0.270      2      2      e    23     <NA>
# 3:      v  1.94      rt  0.419      1      3      r    12     <NA>
# 4:      f  0.37      yh  0.469      6      d      3    67       ty
# 5:      r  1.35      uj  0.132      y      t      4    87     <NA>
# 6:      b  0.75      er  0.865      t      y      5    43     <NA>
# 7:      t  1.95      ed  0.562      4      u      2    23     <NA>
# 8:      o  1.69      we  0.133      6      i      1    12       45
```

Granted, there are likely several things that can go wrong when there are unexpected columns in `map` or `df`.

I added the `if (length(same) && length(diff))` portion so that we don't inadvertently try to join on zero columns or merge in no columns.

---

*Edit*: @MerijnvanTilborg says that `df[map, on=.NATURAL]` will work too ... I haven't tested all corners of it, but it appears to work as desired, recognizing that we need to capture its return value:

```r
map[df, on = .NATURAL] # right output, but ...
df                     # ... but df is unchanged, so ...
df <- map[df, on = .NATURAL]
```

and repeated calls to this does the right thing (i.e., nothing more).

**However**, this will produce different results if there are any 1-to-many or many-to-1 relationships in the join. If that's happening, then either:

- if this is a known 1-to-many relationship, then you may need to add `allow.cartesian=TRUE` inside the brackets; this will never break things if it's not needed, but make sure you know what it means before using it carte-blanche;
- if this is unexpected (i.e., you expect 1-to-1 for all), then check your data for duplicates, bad data, and/or make sure you have all needed join-keys

Comment: if (length(same) && length(diff)) . nice thought.

Comment: I think `map[df, on = .NATURAL]` would do the trick too, and if column order is relevant, one can do `setcolorder(map[df, on = .NATURAL], union(names(df), names(map)))[]`

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg : I would like to use this very much ```map[df, on = .NATURAL]``` but it throws error. ```Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in ******** rows; more than ***** = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. ```

Comment: That means there is a 1-to-many or many-to-1 mapping between your `df` and `map` frames. If that is not intended, then check for duplicates, bad data, or perhaps you need to add more keys to merge on. If that is intended, then did you try to add `allow.cartesian=TRUE` as the error message suggested? (It will return more rows than you start with.)

Comment: @Mohit, I really don't know what your current/real data looks like, so I can't really say why the code above that works with simpler/smaller data is not working there for you. FYI, Merijn's code can expand based on the keys and rows found; the first join (that uses `mget` internally) may be silently not processing extra joins, hiding the cartesian join potential. If this does not make sense, I encourage you to ask a new question about it. (I _am_ glad that the original `mget`-based code is working. Thanks for the feedback!)