# R, create an additional column in a data frame/data.table from a mapping table with certain conditions

Tags: r, data.table

I have these 2 table and I need the column to be created which doesn't appears.

This is an extension of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77204128/match-the-columns-of-a-table-from-another-table-to-get-the-desired-column-in-the) which was asked by me previously.
there is certain modification so I am posting another question.

```
df <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(types=c("x","y","x","x","x","x","x","z","z","y","z","z"),class = c("a", "c", "v", "f", "r", "b", "t", "o","z","c","l","e"), value = c(0.76, 0.91, 1.94, 0.37, 1.35, 0.75, 1.95, 1.69,0,0.9,0.1,0.17), vehicle = c("we", "df", "rt", "yh", "uj", "er", "ed", "we","x","rt","xt","ca"), carbon = c(0.984, 0.27, 0.419, 0.469, 0.132, 0.865, 0.562, 0.133,0.05,0.001,0.7,0.37), cap = c("3", "2", "1", "6", "y", "t", "4", "6","e","4",6,"e"), up = c(4, 2, 3, "d", "t", "y", "u", "i","d","y",4,"t"), down = c("t", "e", "r", 3, 4, 5 ,2,1,2,5,1,2), amt = c(34, 23, 12, 67, 87, 43, 23, 12,34,15,14,45)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" )));
map <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(types=c("x","x","x","y","z","z"),up = c("d", "y", 4,"","",""), vehicle = c("yh", "er", "we","","",""), exercise = c("ty", 45, "k","cf","th","sh"),class = c("","","","c","",""),cap = c("","","","",6,"e"),down = c("","","","",1,2)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L)));
```

In short the vector `exercise` needs to be created in `df`.

Conditions which needs to be met are.

mapping needs to be created using the columns which exist in `df`.

create a mapping out of the vectors `up`, `vehicle`, `class`, `cap` and `down` and look for these items in `df` and fit the value of `exercise` in `df`.

for e.g.

complications are not all items appear in each columns of mapping table `map`.

example 1.
match the columns `up` and `vehicle`, to get the exercise value to be inserted in df.

example 2.

in the `map` , column `class`, for this nothing appears in any of the other corresponding rows for the value `c`. so for this wherever there is `c` in vector `class` of table `df`, value of `exercise` should be `cf`.

example 3.

similarly

use column `cap` and `dowm` in the `map` to the value of `exercise`.

some more explanation below.

There wont be any clash and a unique mapping exist for all entries of `df`.

there is an additional column `types` which separates these different kinds of mapping.

for `x` the columns `up` and `vehicle` will always be present.
for `y` the column `class` will always be present.
for `z` the columns `cap` and `down` will always be present

code can be written with or without the use of `types` column.

so if there is nothing in the `up`, `vehicle`, `cap` and `down`. only the column `class` to be used of the table `map`.

consider only those column/s which has some value appearing in `map` needs to be used to create a mapping.

ideally the new vector in the `df` would look like this
`exercise<-c("k","cf","","ty","",45,"","th","sh","cf","th","sh")`

Comment: Is there a known priority? Like, let's say you had a row in `df` that has `up = 4` and `vehicle = "yh"`, so from the first row of `map` we would expect `exercise = "ty"` to be the result. But what if that same row also had `class = "c"`, which from row 4 of `map` should indicate `exercise = "cf"`. Should the result be `"yh"` or `"cf"` or something else? Or are you certain that such contradictions won't come up?

Comment: Also, the way you've constructed `map`, certain columns seem to always go together... `up` and `vehicle` are always either both present or both absent, same with `cap` and `down`. Is that the case for your real data? Or will there be times where `up` is present but `vehicle` is missing?

Comment: @GregorThomas, there will not be any clash. I have now created an additional column ```types``` in both ```df``` and ```map```  But I am certain there wont be any such contradictions. code can be written with or without the use of ```types```. Thank you so much.
to you other question. there aren't any conditions in ```df``` , i.e. whether any column is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Consider all the columns in ```map``` together is available if not then only the one which is available. Yes you are right @GregorThomas in saying ```up``` and ```vehicle``` will appear together and same for ```cap``` and ```down```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *for x the columns up and vehicle will always be present. for y the*
> *column class will always be present. for z the columns cap and down*
> *will always be present*

This consistent type structure allows us to split the map table by type, and then remove the empty columns. So we have three consistent and different map tables we do a natural join (join with all common columns) using data.table's `on = .NATURAL` with with the original. Then we combine the exercise results of all three joins with `fcoalesce`.

```
df[, exercise := fcoalesce(lapply(split(map, by = "types"), \(x) {
  x[, .SD, .SDcols = \(x) !all(x == "")][df, exercise, on = .NATURAL]
}))]
```

**results**

```
df

    types class value vehicle carbon cap up down amt exercise
 1:     x     a  0.76      we  0.984   3  4    t  34        k
 2:     y     c  0.91      df  0.270   2  2    e  23       cf
 3:     x     v  1.94      rt  0.419   1  3    r  12     <NA>
 4:     x     f  0.37      yh  0.469   6  d    3  67       ty
 5:     x     r  1.35      uj  0.132   y  t    4  87     <NA>
 6:     x     b  0.75      er  0.865   t  y    5  43       45
 7:     x     t  1.95      ed  0.562   4  u    2  23     <NA>
 8:     z     o  1.69      we  0.133   6  i    1  12       th
 9:     z     z  0.00       x  0.050   e  d    2  34       sh
10:     y     c  0.90      rt  0.001   4  y    5  15       cf
11:     z     l  0.10      xt  0.700   6  4    1  14       th
12:     z     e  0.17      ca  0.370   e  t    2  45       sh
```

**data**

```
df <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(types=c("x","y","x","x","x","x","x","z","z","y","z","z"),class = c("a", "c", "v", "f", "r", "b", "t", "o","z","c","l","e"), value = c(0.76, 0.91, 1.94, 0.37, 1.35, 0.75, 1.95, 1.69,0,0.9,0.1,0.17), vehicle = c("we", "df", "rt", "yh", "uj", "er", "ed", "we","x","rt","xt","ca"), carbon = c(0.984, 0.27, 0.419, 0.469, 0.132, 0.865, 0.562, 0.133,0.05,0.001,0.7,0.37), cap = c("3", "2", "1", "6", "y", "t", "4", "6","e","4",6,"e"), up = c(4, 2, 3, "d", "t", "y", "u", "i","d","y",4,"t"), down = c("t", "e", "r", 3, 4, 5 ,2,1,2,5,1,2), amt = c(34, 23, 12, 67, 87, 43, 23, 12,34,15,14,45)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" )));
map <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(types=c("x","x","x","y","z","z"),up = c("d", "y", 4,"","",""), vehicle = c("yh", "er", "we","","",""), exercise = c("ty", 45, "k","cf","th","sh"),class = c("","","","c","",""),cap = c("","","","",6,"e"),down = c("","","","",1,2)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L)));
```

**EDIT - solution without *types***

```
# remove the type columns in both tables
df2 <- df[, types := NULL]
map2 <- map[, types := NULL]

# create the types for the map table
map2[, types := apply(.SD, 1, \(x) paste(which(x != ""), collapse = ""))]

# same as the previous answer
df2[, exercise := fcoalesce(lapply(split(map2, by = "types"), \(x) {
  x[, .SD, .SDcols = \(x) !all(x == "")][df2, exercise, on = .NATURAL]
}))]
```

**result**

```
df2

    class value vehicle carbon cap up down amt exercise
 1:     a  0.76      we  0.984   3  4    t  34        k
 2:     c  0.91      df  0.270   2  2    e  23       cf
 3:     v  1.94      rt  0.419   1  3    r  12     <NA>
 4:     f  0.37      yh  0.469   6  d    3  67       ty
 5:     r  1.35      uj  0.132   y  t    4  87     <NA>
 6:     b  0.75      er  0.865   t  y    5  43       45
 7:     t  1.95      ed  0.562   4  u    2  23     <NA>
 8:     o  1.69      we  0.133   6  i    1  12       th
 9:     z  0.00       x  0.050   e  d    2  34       sh
10:     c  0.90      rt  0.001   4  y    5  15       cf
11:     l  0.10      xt  0.700   6  4    1  14       th
12:     e  0.17      ca  0.370   e  t    2  45       sh
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the same result without fixing the column ```types```.  I would like to know if it can done without using ```types```.

Comment: @Mohit, yes that seems possible, I added that to my answer

Comment: Please I would like to request an additional feature to be included in the code. Awaiting your reply. I have posted another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77462435/r-include-a-column-in-a-data-table-with-certain-conditions