# Perform a something similar to countifs of Excel in R, with a condition

Tags: r, data.table

Assume this is my data.

```
dt <- data.table(F = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 4, 6, 7, 5),
                 M = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "c", "a", "d", "d", "b", "b", "d", "c"));
colnames(dt)=c("She","He");
```

Please use data.table package or anything very efficient so that it can be used on a very large dataset.

- I need to identify the error here.
- 6 is an error here, as it should have only one type of value. i.e. 6 has a value of a and b, which is an error. you will notice all other have only a single type of value.
- I wish to create a column to the right giving 0 if error and 1 if correct.
- Sorting/ordering shouldn't be done.
- Don't aggregate.

ideal solution would be this:

```
c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: FYI, it is usually a bad idea to mask base R objects with variable names. In this case, my eyes (and Stack interface color-themes) want `F` to be R's abbreviated `FALSE`, so it can be momentarily confusing. Further, while often things just work, "future me" would have a difficult time going through past code and seeing (for instance) `dt[,error := +(uniqueN(M)>1), F]` and wondering why I'm passing "false" as the third argument ... this is almost entirely subjective, but my experience shows me that I cannot always trust code I wrote 5 years ago :-)

Comment: Can you write the correct ‘’’dt’’’ which I should have used?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you _not use `F`_ as a variable name. That's all, and it is merely a recommendation by someone who has worked with lots of code (mine and others). Perhaps use `Female` instead of `F`, or `She` or `Fem` or just about anything else that is not as terse and does not collide with a base R variable that is used a lot.

Comment: Changed the column names, so that you are happy.

Comment: The reply was snarky (Sorry about that). I completely agree with your point. I genuinely appreciate all your advice and suggestions in my past questions as well. It's just that you seem to be a perfectionist only sometimes, or maybe you only act this way towards me. for e.g. the question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77204128/match-the-columns-of-a-table-from-another-table-to-get-the-desired-column-in-the) asked by me earlier you never replied back in the comments as soon as I gave it a tick. Similar behavior's I have noticed in the past.

Comment: You replied over 8 hours after my last comment. We don't get "chat" notifications in the Stack interface. Since you had been responsive up until that point, I assumed you had found what you needed, I wasn't going to wait around for hours for replies, and i didn't go back the next day for whatever reason. The chat system is a bit broken.

Comment: I apologize if I may have misunderstood your point. I would like to kindly emphasize in more easy terms.

1. Requesting clarification is a valid and important aspect of effective communication, and I think it is my right to seek clarity.

2. Given your inclination towards perfection and attention to detail, I kindly suggest that you may be able to enhance your commenting and replying skills to an even higher standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dt[,error := +(length(unique(M))>1), F][]
    F M error
 1: 1 a     0
 2: 2 b     0
 3: 3 c     0
 4: 4 b     0
 5: 5 c     0
 6: 6 a     1
 7: 7 d     0
 8: 7 d     0
 9: 4 b     0
10: 6 b     1
11: 7 d     0
12: 5 c     0
```

---

Note that data.table provides `uniqueN` function for doing `length(unique(..))` -- reminded by [@ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376288/r-perform-a-someting-similiar-to-countifs-of-excel-in-r-with-a-condition/77376349?noredirect=1#comment136409683_77376349)

use

```
dt[,error := +(uniqueN(M)>1), F][]
```

Comment: `uniqueN(M)` can replace `length(unique(M))`